# Babelify isn't transpiling jsx code in node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, jsx

I have successfully configured Babelify to transpile jsx code to js, and I have made node_modules in the past, so I can link them without a specific file location, only the package name. But when I include jsx code in my node_module code, babelify reports unexpected tokens where I try to use html tag style data. I'm making my own version of react-bootstrap to better suit my needs. I looked at what react-bootstrap did and they didn't even use jsx, they use React.createElement calls. Is it impossible to use jsx in node modules? That would be an odd limitation.

My goal is to be able to 'require' modules I write without specifying the specific file path, only the package name. When I work outside the node_module file the my code compiles.

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "react-bootstrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.jsx"
}
```

When I only specify the package name in the 'require,' Babelify only looks in the node_module file, if there is a package.json command to look in some other folders as well, something like that might solve my problem. Unless that also compiles only js not jsx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Each modules that needs to be babelified needs to specify the babelify transform in their package.json.

When I compile I use the command:

```
watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --preset [ react ] ] -o public/js/index.js
```

Because I set the babelify react preset in my command I thought it would work everywhere. I found out that I could use:

```
watchify src/main.jsx -v -t -o public/js/index.js
```

If I add:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["react"] }]]
  },
```

To my package.json. So I just added this the above command to my react-bootstrap package.json.